# xUnitTest pipeline exectution Sql on premious

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, azure-devops

- I have a xUnitTest project in .Net core 2.2 that connect with SQL Server database on premise, if i run the unit test in my machine works perfectly.
- I use Azuredevops my source control repository. I made one pipeline build, well that is my problem how can i made my local sql database available to run unitTest in azuredevops pipeline?

xUnitTest works well without sql connection

I expected that xUnitTest connect to my sqlserver database to execute xunitTest

Comment: If your tests use a database, then they are **not** unit tests; they are *integration* tests. Well-written integration tests should manage all of the test data they need themselves, not rely on an externally-managed database.

Comment: @DanielMann even if they aren't unit tests the xUnit framework is fine to use. Also there is data driven testing.

Comment: @FeRaaC I wasn't commenting on the choice of framework. I was commenting on the incorrect terminology and suggesting that the tests should be written so that they manage the test data they need, instead of relying on a particular database.

Comment: @DanielMann I read a few xs to much there tbh. I agree, either the tests manage the data or if they are data driven the data source should be under subversion control as well and is deployed accordingly within the pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your database is only available locally and not shipped with whatever project you are testing. Your problem most likely is that in your pipeline you use a microsoft-hosted agent to build your project(s) and test them. And the microsoft-hosted agent then can't connect to your local database.

Now there is two possibilities you could use.

First, you could [deploy your sql database](https://dzone.com/articles/deploying-databases-using-azure-devops-pipelines) to the agent. You could also use and deploy to [Azure SQL databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/azure-sqldb?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

Second, if you want to keep the database locally, you could set up a [self-hosted azure pipeline agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) which has the SQL database accessable and create a [agent pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops) with your newly created agent. Afterwards you need to configure the build definition in your pipeline to use the correct agent pool.